# how loading progress bar works in Firefox when content-length is not present in headers

Tags: firefox, progress-bar, loading

I want to know how the web page loading progress bar works in FF when there is no content-length present in the http headers. I checked with google.com, it does not send content-length header but the progress bar works correctly. Is it a real progress bar or a fake one? If this is a fake one then how I can build a similar one.

I am building a iPhone app where I need to build a similar loading progress bar.

**Update 1**

@Robot Woods - I just searched "hello" on  the google and I do see the progress bar at the bottom .. right now I am on Windows 7 and FF 3.6.13

[image]

Here is the response headers I am getting -

[image]

And I don't see any content length header...

How FF can generate a progress bar if the content length is not present.. ??

Comment: can you give a little more detail on the example you're looking at? when I _search_ on google I don't see the progress bar (FF 3.6.17), so I can't replicate your scenario to test against. I do see the bar when I load the initial google.com page, but the content-length header is included there, so I can see that's not the situation you're working on. Thanks.

Comment: @Robot Woods - see the edited question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know what Firefox does, but if it were me, I'd look at the following:

The initial page usually loads pretty quickly. Start parsing it while it's still coming in and start grabbing the other resources (css, js, images, etc) the page calls for.

Use the progress bar to depict how long the supporting files are going to take, and estimate the page based on a pessimistic average of other files of that type that you've downloaded before.

What a lot of programs do with their progress bar when that have no information is provide a progress bar that slows down as it gets close to the end.  It never quite reaches the end, but it continues to move as long as data continues to come in.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but can you please explain a bit how should I implement this for iPhone sdk. How can I increase the progress bar if I don't have total size of the page?

Comment: @Saurabh Re-read the last paragraph of my answer. As an example, if you don't know the size of the page, you can increase the progress bar by 1/2 the remainder of the bar every second.  So for the first second, go to 50%.  For the second second, go to 75%.  For the third second go to 87.5%.  Each time go half the remaining distance.  That way the user sees there's progress, but you won't actually reach the end of the bar while you're still loading.  Once you have the page, go to 100%.

Comment: Thanks Much!! If I don't get any more good answer then I'll award the bounty to you!... Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

But what do you want to load? Is FF just an example of progress bar here?

If you want to connect to a network with NSURLConnection and show it's download progress, you can simply do it with UIProgressView object. Mind that I've skipped your data handling and just wrote the progress event.

```
//NSURLConnection Delegate Methods

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response{

    //length is a long long declared outside
    length =  [response expectedContentLength];

}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data {

    NSNumber * recieved = [NSNumber numberWithUnsignedInteger:[data length]];
    NSNumber * total = [NSNumber numberWithLongLong:length];
    float ratio = [recieved floatValue] / [toplam floatValue];
    [[YourUIProgressView progressBar] setProgress:ratio];

}
```

Good luck.

Comment: I do know the above methods.. but the question is what if the expectedContentLength gives you -1? because google.com don't send content-length header and so the expectedContentLength not correct. But when you visit the google.com in FF you can see a progress bar there...

Comment: and Yes I want to show the progress of a webpage loading. The above page works well if the content-length is present in the header but how to show progress is its not there..

Comment: You can't get accurate progress if it's not there. You can only imitate it. But it won't be reliable for users of course. Sorry can't see what FF has, don't like 3rd party on my mac much.